# puphpet elasticsearch directory

Tags: elasticsearch, puphpet

First time tinkering with ElasticSearch. Installed ES on my VM by adding

```
elastic_search:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '1.4.4'
        java_install: true
```

to config.yaml. Following [THESE INSTRUCTIONS](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_installing_elasticsearch.html) I would now like to perform some actions in the ElasticSearch directory, for example run the following:

```
./bin/plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

Where is the ElasticSearch directory in my VM? Or is this command supposed to be run in my local machine (where)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PuPHPet uses the elastic/puppet-elasticsearch module.

Looking through that code I think one of these directories is the one you want:

https://github.com/elastic/puppet-elasticsearch/blob/master/manifests/params.pp#L98

Elastic Search is *not* installed on your master machine. It exists *only* within the VM you've created. You can access it from the outside, though, just as you would any other service, but actually running any code through shell would require you to be inside the VM.

Comment: Thanks! It was `/usr/share/elasticsearch`.